# Remove matching text in AppleScript

Tags: regex, variables, applescript

With AppleScript I'm running a shell script:

```
set username to (do shell script "whoami")
```

Which will return the username in a way that has our company name pre-prended. Is there a way of finding matched text, and removing it from the username variable?

For example if the username is businessName\username

How can I remove the businessName\

Comment: If this is really about getting the user name, perhaps you'd better set the title to "Getting the user name". No need to mention AppleScript in the title, as it is a tag name.

Comment: But it's not. I *have* the username. I want to remove certain text from the username.

Comment: It looks like adayzdone gave the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
set myText to "businessName\\username"

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "\\"}
set myText to text item 2 of myText
set text item delimiters to TID

return myText
```

Comment: That's great, except it only works if the username has 2 \\ before, we only have one.

Comment: That is how you escape the \ character. Try it with your script.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply retrieve $USER?

```
set currentuser to (do shell script "echo $USER")
```

Another way to do this is

```
set currentuser to system attribute "USER"
```

(mind the use of upper case characters).

Comment: I now understand that you're not looking for the user name but that you want to change the value returned by $USER.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with sed:

```
set username to do shell script "whoami|sed 's/^.*\\\\//'"
```

(The backslash has to be mask with a backslash in bash and both have to be mask with a backslash in applescript.)